# How to combine continuous variables for logistic regression: ratio and absolute numbers

Tags: regression, logistic, data-transformation, predictor, data-preprocessing

I am trying to fit a logistic regression and I have variables which are in terms of ratios and in absolute numbers. How should I treat them? Is it okay to treat them equally, or should the absolute numbers be converted to something else? For example: $x_1$ is variable in terms of ratio, $x_2$ is in absolute numbers. Can I use them for LR as they are? Thanks.

Comment: You can. There is no rule for logistic regression that predictors all have to be the same kind. Equally, nothing rules out transformation of any or even all variables being a better idea for your data.

Comment: For more specific advice we would need more context: What does your variables represent, ...

Comment: I am working with NSL-KDD99 data set, the benchmark data set for intrusion detection techniques. Some of the variables represent count of some measure, some are given as a ratio. Here is a table what I have found on internet, about variables: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oAx320Vo9Z6HrBrL6BcfLH6sh2zIk9EKCv2OlaMGmwY/edit#gid=0